# Как сделать затемнение фона при открытии мобильного меню?

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, что необходимо дописать в JS код, чтобы при открытии моб. меню, фон затемнялся??

```
jQuery('.menu-icon').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('opened'); }); 


$('.icon').on('click', function(){
 $('.mobile-list').slideToggle(); });


$('.icon').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('mobile-menu_active'); })
```

Comment: Но ведь меню - тоже какой-нибудь блок. Присвойте ему [здесь и далее "он" означает контейнер собственно меню] ширину `100vw`, добавьте в него блок с собственно меню с соответствующей шириной. Тогда при "активации" меню останется только изменить фон контейнера меню.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь к меню ещё один класс и к нему допиши :before, который будет растянут по всему экрану с необходимым затемнением, по открытии добавляй этот клас, при закрытии убирай.